# Creating a new environment with one optional argument

Tags: spacing, environments, optional-arguments

I want to create a new environment with one optional argument in LaTeX. Here is what I used:

```
\newenvironment{argument}[1][]{%
\par
\noindent
\textbf{Argument#1:}
\noindent}
{}
```

When there is no argument, it typesets the ':' right after the word 'Argument', which is how it should be.

However, when the optional argument is used, LaTeX doesn't add a space between the word 'Argument' and the optional argument provided.

In other words, what I want to achieve is that if the optional argument is provided (e.g. A), then LaTeX should add a space after the word 'Argument', like:

**Argument A:** some text

and when there is no optional argument, it should be like (without the space):

**Argument:** some text

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Add a space before `#1` in the environment's definition, and specify `\unskip` (which will remove the space)  as the optional argument's default value.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{argument}[1][\unskip]{%
\par
\noindent
\textbf{Argument #1:}
\noindent}
{}

\begin{document}

\begin{argument}
Some text.
\end{argument}

\begin{argument}[A]
Some text.
\end{argument}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice :-) I always used an if clause but this is shorter. It doesn’t work with `{argument}[]` right? This can cause problems when I need to optional arguments like in `\cite[cf.][]{key}`

Answer (score 16):

The definition of a new environment can be done by the basic LaTeX command `\newenvironment`. But I'd like to recommend the package [`xparse`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xparse) which provides also commands and utilities to define new environments; for instance, it provides a simple test to check if the optional argument is empty or not.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
    \NewDocumentEnvironment{argument} { o }
     {
      \par\noindent
      \IfNoValueTF{#1} { \textbf{Argument:~} }{ \textbf{Argument~#1:~} }
       \ignorespaces
     }
     {}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{argument}
some text
\end{argument}
\begin{argument}[A]
some text
\end{argument}
\end{document}
```

The commands `ExplSyntaxOn` & `ExplSyntaxOff` are used to ignore some unwanted spaces inside the definition.

---

The command `ExplSyntaxOn` is the activation of the `expl3` syntax. You can compare it with `makeatletter` for the `@`-symbol. Besides some other definitions, `ExplSyntaxOn` will ignore every space. So `Hello World` would print "HelloWorld". To get a space you must use a tilde `~`. In this way `Hello~World` prints "Hello World". This is the reason why I wrote `\textbf{Argument~#1:~}`.

As egreg pointed out you can also use:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
    \NewDocumentEnvironment{argument} { o }
     {
      \par\noindent
       \textbf{Argument \IfValueT { #1 } { ~ #1 } : ~ }
       \ignorespaces
     }
     {}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

[image]

Comment: I removed the second `\noindent` and used `\ignorespaces` instead.

Comment: There's no need for `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff`, but it's a matter of preference. Probably `\textbf{Argument\IfValueT{#1}{~#1}:~}` would be more efficient and, perhaps, also clearer.

Comment: @egreg: `ExplSyntaxOn` is needed. Please see my sentence under the example. Otherwise I must work with `%`

Comment: Yes, of course! You might expand the note, making clear that `~` should be used for denoting *wanted* spaces: the syntax is probably unfamiliar to Ali.

Comment: @egreg: In this way?

Comment: Very good explanation. :)

Answer (score 7):

I would just put in the space if the optional argument is empty (or not used). Also I removed the second `\noindent` since it can do nothing useful in that position, as the paragraph has already started.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{argument}[1][]{%
\par
\noindent
\textbf{Argument\ifx\newenvironment#1\newenvironment\else\space\fi#1:} }
{}

\begin{document}

\begin{argument}
Some text.
\end{argument}

\begin{argument}[A]
Some text.
\end{argument}

\end{document}
```

Comment: For the case where the optional parameter is not provided this produces an extra space before the colon.

Comment: @PeterGrill apparently `\ifx` doesn'yt include typo-correction:( `\newenvrionment` isn't the same as `\newenvironment` (fixed thanks:-)

Comment: Is there a special reason to use `\newenvironment` in `\ifx` or is it just a dummy and could it be `\tableofcontents`to?

Comment: @Tobi no any command will do, but it needs to be a command that will never be the first token of the optional argument. But you _do_ need to spell it the same way both times:-)

Comment: +1 what a dirty `\ifx` trick!