# Write a macro which is called with \begin and \end

Tags: macros

I would like to write a macro `scaleblock` which takes 2 arguments `title` and `content`. It can be called like:

```
\begin{scaleblock}{a_title}
   a_content
\end{scaleblock}
```

And it is equivalent to the follows:

```
\begin{block}{\scalebox{0.8}{a_title}}
  \scalebox{0.8}{\vbox{a_content}}
\end{block}
```

Does anyone know how to write this kind of macro (with `\begin` and `\end`)?

Comment: Use the command `\newenvironment`.  Look here for previous answer.  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60079/creating-a-new-environment-with-one-optional-argument

Comment: I think `\newenvironment` is yourt friend.

Comment: I don't think that `\newenvironment` can suffice. I believe that `\NewEnviron` from `environ` package is needed, as suggested in cannaerus'es answer.

Comment: @tohez since the body is to be boxed anyway using newenvironment and newenvironment with lrbox as in egreg's answer would have several benefits, especially allowing verb and friends to work

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ok, another approach, but still, the solely link provided by R. Schumacher would not help, you need to add information "... and use `lrbox`. Other than that, I agree that egreg's solution is elegant and efficient!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can define an environment just as you would define a macro. Only instead of saying `\newcommand\mycmd[1]{...#1...}` you must write

```
\newenvironment{myenv}[1]{Begin...#1...}{End}
```

Here the last two parameters say what should be put before and after the contents.

This means the first try would be to write

```
\newenvironment{scaleblock}[1]{\begin{block}{\scalebox{0.4}{#1}}
    \scalebox{0.4}{\vbox{}%
  {}}
\end{block}}
```

But this does not reflect the intended nesting of parameters and you actually only give the begin part of your environment, while the end part is the newline character in the fourth line.

So in your case it is probably better to first collect everything inside the environments body and then use it. This can be done with the `environ` package. It provides the command `\NewEnviron` where you can use `\BODY` to access those content. Assuming `block` is the one from `beamer`, you can do the following:

```
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{scaleblock}[1]{\begin{block}{\scalebox{0.8}{#1}}
  \scalebox{0.8}{\vbox{\BODY}}
\end{block}}
```

Comment: I think it's a beamer block.

Comment: You cannot directly use `#` in the ending part of a `\newenvironment`.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Ah, thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 13):

Here's a "pure LaTeX" version:

```
\newsavebox{\scaleblockbox}
\newenvironment{scaleblock}[1]
  {\begin{block}{\scalebox{0.8}{#1}
   \begin{lrbox}{\scaleblockbox}
   \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}}
  {\end{minipage}
   \end{lrbox}
   \scalebox{0.8}{\usebox{\scaleblockbox}}
   \end{block}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have greater control with keys:

```
\krdmakekeys[
  prefix=KV,
  family=collectbody,
  hp=mp,
  initialize,
  endlinechar=-1
]{%
  cmd/title//,
  zcmd/title scale/1,
  zcmd/body scale/1,
  cmd/width/\textwidth,
  zcmd/title text style//,
  zcmd/body text style//,
  cmd/action//
}

\newsavebox{\boxbody}
\newenvironment{collectbody}[1][]{%
  \krdusekeys[prefix=KV,family=collectbody]{#1}%
  \ifx\mptitle\@empty\else\krdafterfi
    \begin{center}%
    \scalebox{\mptitlescale}{\mptitletextstyle\mptitle}%
    \end{center}%
  \fi
  \begin{lrbox}{\boxbody}%
  \begin{minipage}{\mpwidth}%
  \mpbodytextstyle\mpaction
}{%
  \end{minipage}%
  \end{lrbox}%
  \scalebox{\mpbodyscale}{\usebox{\boxbody}}%
}
```

This may be used as:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsname]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{collectbody}[
  title=Example of collect body,
  title scale=.8,
  title text style=\ttfamily\color{red}
]
\lipsum[1]
\end{collectbody}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT (2012/08/23)**

The above code is based on a version of *keyreader* package that isn't on CTAN. Here is a solution based on *pgfkeys*.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsname]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\def\pgfkeysafterfi#1\fi{\fi#1}
\def\pgfkeysafterelse@i#1\else#2\fi{\fi#1}
\def\pgfkeysifkeydefined#1#2#3{%
  \ifcsname pgfk@#1/.@cmd\endcsname
    \pgfkeysafterelse@i{#2}\else\pgfkeysafterfi{#3}\fi
}
\pgfkeys{
  /handlers/.protected estore in/.code=
    \pgfkeys{
      \pgfkeyscurrentpath/.code=\protected@edef#1{##1}
    },
  /handlers/.default and initial/.code=
    \pgfkeys{
      \pgfkeyscurrentpath/.initial=#1,
      \pgfkeyscurrentpath/.default=#1,
      \pgfkeyscurrentpath=#1%
    },
  /handlers/.new key/.code 2 args=
    \pgfkeysifkeydefined{\pgfkeyscurrentpath}{%
      \@latexerr{Key '\pgfkeyscurrentpath' already exists}\@ehd
    }{%
      \pgfkeys{
        \pgfkeyscurrentpath/.store in=#1,
        \pgfkeyscurrentpath/.default and initial=#2%
      }%
    }%
}
\pgfkeys{%
  /collectbody/.is family,/collectbody/.cd,
  title/.new key=\mptitle\@empty,
  title scale/.new key=\mptitlescale{1},
  body scale/.new key=\mpbodyscale{1},
  width/.new key=\mpwidth\textwidth,
  title text style/.new key=\mptitletextstyle\@empty,
  body text style/.new key=\mpbodytextstyle\@empty,
  action/.new key=\mpaction\@empty
}
\def\@@empty{\@empty}
\newsavebox{\boxbody}
\newenvironment{collectbody}[1][]{%
  \pgfkeys{/collectbody/.cd,#1}%
  \ifx\mptitle\@@empty\else\pgfkeysafterfi
    \begin{center}%
    \scalebox{\mptitlescale}{\mptitletextstyle\mptitle}%
    \end{center}%
  \fi
  \begin{lrbox}{\boxbody}%
  \begin{minipage}{\mpwidth}%
  \mpbodytextstyle\mpaction
}{%
  \end{minipage}%
  \end{lrbox}%
  \scalebox{\mpbodyscale}{\usebox{\boxbody}}%
}
\makeatother

% Example:
\begin{document}
\begin{collectbody}[
  title=Example of \texttt{collect body} environment,
  title scale=.8,
  title text style=\scshape\color{red}
]
\lipsum[1]
\end{collectbody}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Where do those macros `\krdmakekeys` and `\krdusekeys` come from?

Comment: Oops, I am sorry. The package that authored the macros isn't on CTAN. I will change the code soon.