# How to make \left\{ and \right. work in an new environment?

Tags: cases

I have tried to define a new environment `numcases`, which just like the cases except tagging the equations as a whole, and

```
\newenvironment{numcases}{\begin{equation}\left\{\begin{array}{rll}}%
{\end{array}\right.\end{equation}}
```

also I know the `cases` package, but it will tag all lines of equations (not as a whole). I guess that the problem in my definition is that the `\left\{` and `\right.` not in a block (i.e., a `{}`), so any solution?

Comment: Is there really a need for it? Why not
`\begin{equation}\begin{cases}`
`...`
`\end{cases}\end{equation}`
which would be clearer? (Needs `\usepackage{amsmath}`)

Comment: As David pointed out in his answer, the code works just ok. This means that in the present form, there's nothing to answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please *always* post complete documents that show the problem. There is nothing wrong with your fragment so presumably your problem is in a part you have not shown.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{numcases}{\begin{equation}\left\{\begin{array}{rll}}%
{\end{array}\right.\end{equation}}

\begin{document}

\begin{numcases}
a&1&x\\
b&2&y\\
c&3&z
\end{numcases}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, you were definitely right, the problem is in other part. My definition works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

The `environ` package allows you to define such a environment, that first reads the whole body and then puts it into some command. (compare also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/67849/15616)

In your case this should look something like:

```
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{numcases}{%
    \begin{equation}\left\{\begin{array}{rll}%
        \BODY%
    \end{array}\right.\end{equation}}
```

Comment: It does. but there is nothing wrong with there definition as posted either.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Ok, just saw your answer. Good to know, I just did not try it myself ;-)

Comment: Yes, it quite helpful in some other circumstances.