# Define an environment that by default load some options

Tags: listings, environments

Is there a way to define a new `listings` environment with some `listings` options by default?

For example, I am hoping to define a new environment, say `myenv`, such that

```
\begin{myenv}
\end{myenv}
```

and

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language = Java , frame = trBL , escapeinside={(*@}{@*)}, escapechar=\%]
\end{lstlisting}
```

are the same

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60079/117274 for a start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defining new verbatim environments is different from defining normal environment. `listings` already provides `\lstnewenvironment` for that

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstnewenvironment{myenv}
    {\lstset{language = Java , frame = trBL , escapeinside={(*@}{@*)}, escapechar=\%}}
    {}
\begin{document}
\begin{myenv}
```

```java
/* HelloWorld.java
 */

public class HelloWorld
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

```
\end{myenv}
\end{document}
```

[image]

`Hello world` Java code taken from [here](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~scottm/cs307/javacode/codeSamples/HelloWorld.java).